# Javascript: Calculate time between today and a specific following weekday time

Tags: javascript, time

I'm looking for a method to calculate the time in seconds between now UTC-7 and the following Saturday (independent of the date the calculation is being done) at a specific UTC-7 time (08:00) in Javascript.

Currently I am using this code but i want to replace giving specific dates with the abovementioned calculation:

```
// Grab the current date
var now = new Date();
var currentDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds()); currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() - 7);

// Set some date in the future. 
var ClashDate  = new Date("August 6, 2017 16:40:00");
var BashDate  = new Date("August 12, 2017 08:00:00");

// Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
var diffclash = ClashDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
var diffbash = BashDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
```

Could anyone help me out?

Yours sincerely
Yamper

Comment: Sorry, that comment is from an old version (I changed that but not the comment). I'll remove it from the code now.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity you can use `MomentJS` to dynamically figure out the dates for the following `Saturday` and the next `Saturday` after it.

To instance a `Moment` date for this coming `Saturday` you can do it through the `.day(int)` API. E.g. `.day(6)`.

To get the `epoch` time you can do `.unix()` but there is a catch here. By default it returns you `seconds` since `epoch` not the standard milliseconds.

**Example:**

```js
var now = new Date();
var currentDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds()); currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() - 7);

moment().tz("America/New_York").format();

// Set some date in the future.
var ClashDate = moment().day("Saturday").hour(16).minutes(40).seconds(0);
var BashDate = moment().day(13).hour(8).minutes(0).seconds(0);

console.log("Next Saturday date is => " + ClashDate.toString());
console.log("Next Next Saturday date is => " + BashDate.toString());

// Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
var diffclash = ClashDate.unix()  - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
var diffbash = BashDate.unix() - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

console.log("diffClash => " + diffclash);
console.log("diffBash => " + diffbash);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

**Reference:**

MomentJS - https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Thank you but the script works just fine like that. This is not the problem. I just want to replace giving a specific date with a calculation that calculates the distance to the following Saturday (weekday) every time so I do not have to update the date in the script every week.

Comment: @Yamper thanks for the comment. I have revamped the solution.

Comment: Again, thank you for your code. I just do not understand because your script still states specific times and i dont want to calculate "6 days 16 hours from now" but instead a script that calculates these values based on the difference between now and next saturday. I basically need the datetime of "next saturday" 8:00 am independent of whether im doing the calculation now or next week. It's always supposed to be "the following saturday".

Comment: From my understanding the `day` api does not mean to add "6" days from today's date and hence giving you `Saturday`. `6` here means I want the date for this coming `Saturday`. I have updated my solution to use the keyword `Saturday` to prove that I am not hardcoding to add 6 days.

Comment: Essentially the code is building a `Date` which would be this coming Saturday at `4PM` is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you, I now understand that better. Could you maybe also tell me where to enter the time in UTC -7 format so that the time being put out is the same for each person, independent of where he/she lives? I assume "var ClashDate = moment().day("Saturday").hour(8).minutes(00).seconds(0);" would be 8:00 local time only. My issue is that I want the output to be the same for everybody, independent of where on the world he/she lives.

Comment: You can set the default timezone for `moment` by doing `moment().tz("America/New_York").format();` See updated solution. You can also set the `tz` for individual `moment object`. Recommend reading their documentation, definitely will worth your time as momentJS is a very established JS library for date time. http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to use your script as well. There seems to be just one problem with the script. When I'm looking at "Sunday 08:00 AM", it puts out today even though in the given timezone its already Sunday 09:00 PM. (It should put out next week's Sunday because it is already past the given time today) The function seems to struggle when the weekday it is being run on is the same. Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

In POJS, (one way) you can get the next Saturday at a particular time as follows.

```js
function nextSaturday(date) {
  const d = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (6 - d.getDay()) % 7);
  return new Date(`${d.toISOString().split('T').shift()}T14:00:00.000Z`);
}

console.log(nextSaturday('2017-08-13'));
console.log(nextSaturday('2017-08-31'));
console.log(nextSaturday());
```

Comment: Thank you Xotic. May I ask where in your code I can specify the time at "next saturday" in UTC -7 ? I do want to run the following calculation "var diffclash = ClashDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;" with your variable instead of "ClashDate.getTime()".

Comment: `T17:00:00.000Z === 08:00:00.00(UTC-7)` If I counted correctly. Of course you can add another argument for time, to make it more generic if you want. But this is the basic principle.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works great. I just had to modify the time to "T14:00:00.000Z" (which is UTC-7).

Comment: Damn, hard to count this time of the morning. :P